# Upload Image to s3 Using DelayedJobActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, delayed-job

I am trying to upload image using DelayedJobActiveRecord. But when I try to add it in DelayedJob as follow

```
AmazonService.delay.amazon_s3_store_image(image.last["image"], key)

###image.last["image"]

#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004c0ff40
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers=
  "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"GALAXY_SIII_mini_Product_Image4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @original_filename="GALAXY_SIII_mini_Product_Image4.jpg",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140524-3636-3bt3se>>

### key

"e6368079c2c6cdb4dbdaf6e5c03f2f"

def amazon_s3_store_image(image, key)
  BUCKET.objects[key].write(image, acl: :public_read)
  url = BUCKET.objects[key].public_url(secure: false)
  url.scheme + "://" + url.host + url.path
end
```

**Exact Error message**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
from /home/awais/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:70:in `block in initialize'
```

I know how to do it with sidekiq, but unfortunately i have less memory issues, because of which I want to do it using DelayedJob.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace of the exception? And perhaps the full delayed job payload object?

Comment: Since it appears to be a YAML issue I'm inclined to think it has to do with your payload object's de-serialization. That's why it'd help to see the code for the payload object (the object which has the `perform` method in it). Anyway, it's hard to tell from here... have you tried adding a debugger in the `perform` action to make sure (a) it's getting into there and (b) `image.last["image"]` actually is what you expect it to be?

Comment: @pdobb my bad i forgot to add `.delay` in the first line updated again AmazonService.delay.amazon_s3_store_image(image.last["image"], key)

Answer (score 0):

When enqueuing a Delayed Job, the gem must serialize all of the data needed to perform the action into the database. So, typically you don't want to serialize e.g. an entire object (such as a User or whatever) because then all of the attributes of the user are serialized into the database -- which is extra work and may provide stale data by the time the job gets run! But, in your case, it sounds like you're asking Delayed Job to try to serialize an image file into the database! Which, it sounds like it's failing on. (Try running `image.last["image"].to_yaml` in a debugger and see what you get!)

So, to get this working in Delayed Job you'll probably need to create a [custom Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#custom-jobs) that references an image previously stored in a temporary location on the file system or something like that. This is certainly extra work... but I don't think there's any way around this. I had to do this sort of thing for uploading generated PDFs to AWS in the past.

**Note**: There is also the additional headache that when you store the image to the filesystem temporarily, then run the delayed job later... the image has to be stored on the same file system as the one the delayed job runs on or it won't find it!